# Why is it that Btrees most of the times have a degree that is odd? What happens if they are even?

Tags: b-tree

I was watching a lecture video and the Professor states that it would be very rare to see the order of a Btree to be even. I was hoping for an explanation but he cut it off there and moved on with the lecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a right answer to this but you could argue for a preference either way.

Let's define B-tree order `m` like this

- max children/values `m`
- min children/values `m/2`
- max keys `m-1`
- min keys `Math.ceil(m/2)-1`

  - `Math.ceil` is only needed if `m` is *odd*

If `m` is even, the you have an odd number of keys. For example `[a b c]`, we could split this either `[a b] [c]` (left bias) or `[a] [b c]` (right bias). If `m` is odd you have an even number of keys. `[a b c d]` would always split into `[a b] [c d]`.

The opposite is true for values. i.e. when you have an even number of keys you have an odd number of values. In which case you need to pick either a left or right bias.

If you declare upfront that you won't deal with odd or even you get a little bit less to think about.

Other than that, it's an arbitrary decision. There's no benefit to either choice.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that distinguishes real-world B-trees from "lecture B-trees" is that real B-trees tend to have nodes and leaves where the size *in bytes* is fixed. So the "degree" of a B-tree is determined by the number of keys that will fit on a page.

So if the keys vary in size (e.g. strings), the "degree" of different nodes may be different. Roughly 50% of them will have even degree.